# SQL: Extracting rows with a certain value from customerID column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query result that outputs `customerID` and transaction descrip.

From the same query, I actually want to only extract the transaction `descript = 'refund'` from all the customers. Some customers do not have the 'refund' value and if so, return as null value
ex)

This is the result I get from the query:

| CustomerID A | Descrip. B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | purchase |
| 1 | refund |
| 2 | refund |
| 3 | purchase |
| 4 | purchase |

But it should be like this:

| CustomerID A | Descrip. B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | refund |
| 2 | refund |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | null |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select CustomerID, 
       max(case when Descrip = 'refund' then Descrip else null end) as Description 
from your_table_query
group by CustomerID
```

Comment: is it possible to add more values in the CASE WHEN statement? So, not just 'refund' but also 'cancelled' under the new column name Description

Comment: Well, that changes your entire question. It depends on the logic you expect.